# Orthogonal complement of certain family of functions.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

We know that the linear span of subspace $A$ in Hilbert space $X$ is dense if orthogonal complement of $A$, that is $A^{\bot}$ is trivial. I am given a family of functions $A=\{f_n\}$ and I was trying to construct $A^{\bot}$ with just one function, say $g(x)$ so that $g$ is orthogonal to all $f_n$, so that I could conclude that $A$ is not dense in X. But I ended up in constructing a family of functions $B=\{g_n\}$ with $g_n$ and$f_n$  pairwise orthogonal,that is $<f_n,g_n>=0$ for each $n$. My $g_n$'s heavily depend on $f_n's$ for each $n$.

I cannot conclude $A$ is dense, right? From the collection $B$, can I just construct a one function say $g(x)$ which is orthogonal to all of $f_n$?

Comment: It seems like there's a lot of information you're not providing.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the data you have given, you cannot conclude that $A$ is dense in $A$.  Because if $\{f_n\}$ is an orthogonal family in $X$, then letting $g_n=f_{n+1}$, we would have $\langle f_n,g_n\rangle=0$ for all $n$, but $\operatorname{span}\{g_n\}\subset\operatorname{span}\{f_n\}$.

Comment: The given family $A=\{f_n\}$ is not orthogonal. Rather, I am looking for a non-zero function $g(x)$ which is orthogonal to each member in $A$. But I got the family of $g_n$'s, each orthogonal to $f_n$ pairwise not a 'universal' $g(x)$. From these $g_n$'s I want to construct $g$.  I think I have provided all the information in my post except the equations of $f_n$ and $g_n$.

Comment: The point of my example is that, in the generality you have provided, one cannot expect to find anything outside of the span of the $f_n$ if you only have functions $g_n$ such that $\langle f_n, g_n\rangle=0$.

Comment: I think I should be able to create $g(x)$ from $g_n$'s. May be as the sum of of all $g_n$'s (provided sum converges which I have to check) such that $<f_n,g>=0$. My inner product is $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} f_n g dx$. It seems I should be able to create such $g$ from $g_n$ by using Kronecr delta like functions.

Comment: You were right, the question is in more generality. I should have atleast mentiod my Hilbert space and inner product I am working in! Will try to edit the question tommorow.